# Java - How to auto generate input fields?

Tags: java, input, field, dynamically-generated

I'm working, trying and failing on this for quite some time now. I need to generade extra input fields. In my SQL database i got two tables, one which says how many extra fields i need to generate and what type(for starters just input fields). And another table where i get my data to write into those fields. So i get all this data as JSON String and i translate them into Strings. Now i got all this data as Strings and based on this data i need to generate x fields of the type y(in this case input fields).

As the code is now it just generates a input field. I just have no idea how to connect the info and the creation of the fields :(

This is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectZusatz = new JSONObject(ZusatzString); 
int ZusatzJSONlength = jsonObjectZusatz.length();
for(int key1 = 0; key1 < ZusatzJSONlength; key1++){
  JSONObject jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0 = jsonObjectZusatz.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(key1));  
  String ZusatzNameJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("name");  // String auslesen!!!
  String ZusatzTypJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("typ");  // String auslesen!!!
  String ZusatzEintragJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("eintrag");  // String auslesen!!!

  JTextField ZFtextField = new JTextField();
  ZFtextField.setBounds(118, 260, 136, 20);
  contentPane2.add(ZFtextField);
  ZFtextField.setColumns(10);

  JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Stuff:");
  lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
  lblNewLabel.setBounds(12, 263, 46, 14);
  contentPane2.add(lblNewLabel);
```

thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the partial for loop that you are giving, it would seem that the JTextField and the corresponding labels are all created indeed. However since the values in the setBounds() are not incremented on each iteration of the loop, all your label and text fields are superposed. That would be why you only can see one.

To solve this, when you give you (x,y) positions of your objects, instead of (value1, value2), you should put (value1 + key1 * xGap, value2 + key1 * yGap). Here it's your loop index that will tell you how far you should move your element.

Comment: Yeah i know that, i just placed it here statically, but the thing is that i dont know how to generate it with the given data :/

Comment: when you give you (x,y) positions, instead of _(value1, value2)_, you should put _(value1 + key1 * xGap, value2 + key1 * yGap)_.
Here it's your loop index that will tell you how far you should move your element.

Comment: Ahh oke, but the main problem is how can i name the elements dynamically? because i think that i cant have two input fields with the same name

Comment: your name should be in `String ZusatzNameJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("name");` why not just use that?

Comment: if i do it like this:  if(ZusatzTypJSON.equals("input")){
 JTextField ZusatzNameJSON = new JTextField();
 ZFtextField.setBounds(118, xValue, 136, 20);
 contentPane2.add(ZFtextField);
 ZFtextField.setColumns(10);
} it gives me errors. Sorry dont know how to format it in comments

Comment: which errors? Also naming variables with a first capital letters is bad practice, it makes the code difficult to read

Comment: It says: Duplicate local variable